# how we can call the object of second call in the first class in java

Tags: java

here i have a code which i am giving u please correct my code and run it when i enter the extend or make object of attendence class in the student class then attendence class is not worked

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Attendence {
    private int c;
    public Attendence(){

    }
    public void project(){

        System.out.println("Enter the total no of students of the class");
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int c=input.nextInt();
        String[][] array=new String[c][6];

        for(int i=0; i<c; i++){
            for(int j=0;j<6;j++){
                  array[i][j]=input.next();
            }}
          System.out.println("RollNO \t       Name \t       Class \t     Attendence Mark \tTeacher Name \tSubject Name");
            for(int k=0; k<c; k++){
                for(int l=0;l<6;l++){

                     System.out.print(array[k][l]+    "\t\t"     );

                     }
                 System.out.println("\n");

            }
            }}
```

here this is second class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class student extends Attendence {


    private int password;
    private String ID;
    public student(int passsword , String ID){
        super();
        this.password= password;
        this.ID=ID;


    }



    public int getPassword() {
        return password;
    }



    public void setPassword(int password) {
        this.password = password;
    }



    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }



    public void setID(String iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }



    public void mainfunction(){
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the password");
        int password=input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("enter the ID");
        String ID=input.next();
        if(password==123 || ID=="abc"){

            System.out.println("u enter right password and ID so you can acess the Attendance sheet");

        }
        else
            System.out.println("u enter wrong password and ID so you can't acess the Attendance sheet");
    }





    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.getPassword()+ this.getID()+super.toString();

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Attendence z = new Attendence();
        student a=new student(123, "abc");
        //a.mainfunction();

        a.mainfunction();

        z.project();
    }
}
```

Comment: its working fine..what exactly is not happening in your code

Comment: but in not working in my eclipse its not axcess the first class and take input but not gave output of attendance sheet

Comment: what error you are getting??

Answer (score 0):

It is working as expected.
I tried to execute your code got following output . check it this is what you expect.
enter the password
123
enter the ID
abc
u enter right password and ID so you can acess the Attendance sheet
Enter the total no of students of the class
1

2
xyz
2
2
2
abc
RollNO         Name            Class         Attendence Mark    Teacher Name                                                                                                                                           S
ubject Name
2               xyz               2               2               abc

or else ask precisely what you exactly want.

Comment: i want that first its ask the password and id then its acess the attendence class and take input of the attendence sheet and provide output like this which you show up

Comment: That is not an answer. Sorry, but you would write comment for such "please refine the question". I know, you can't yet, but still. Answers should be answers.

Comment: please be quick i want to do more work in it and time is short

Comment: It is asking for password and id.. check the above post.

Comment: i know its ask the password and id but its not take input of the student class actully that is my problem

Comment: you want to say that i should run the code in eclipse its working

Comment: i have got the point enter the password
123
enter the ID
abc
u enter right password and ID so you can acess the Attendance sheet
Enter the total no of students of the class
1
1
ali
14-18
tahir
english now its not show the output of the class student

Comment: please help me please

Comment: yeah it is same like me

Answer (score 0):

Call the Attendance class in if loop(if password and ID is correct)..and close the input(Scanner) object..

**`Student.class`**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Student extends Attendence {
    private int password;
    private String ID;

    public Student(int passsword, String ID) {
        super();
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student a = new Student(123, "abc");
        a.mainfunction();
    }

    public void mainfunction() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the password");
        int password = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter the ID");
        String ID = input.next();
        if (password == 123 || ID == "abc") {
            System.out.println("u enter right password and ID so you can acess the Attendance sheet");
            Attendence z = new Attendence();
            z.project();
        } else {
            System.out.println("u enter wrong password and ID so you can't acess the Attendance sheet");
        }
        input.close();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getPassword() + this.getID() + super.toString();

    }

    public int getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(int password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(String iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }
}
```

**`Attendance.class`**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Attendence {

    public void project() {
        System.out.println("Enter the total no of students of the class");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Integer c = input.nextInt();
        String[][] array = new String[c][6];

        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the Roll No,Name,Class,Attendance Mark,Teacher Name,Student Name for student "+(i+1));
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                array[i][j] = input.next();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("RollNO \t Name \t Class \t Attendence Mark \tTeacher Name \t Subject Name");
        for (int k = 0; k < c; k++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < 6; l++) {
                System.out.print(array[k][l] + "\t\t");
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```